# What is the best way to handle iPad/iPhone views?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, interface, builder

I'm developping an iPhone/iPad application and I want to make specific views for both iPad and iPhone. I was wondering what was the best way to select the handle the view selection.

Should I create a MainViewController with a custom push method which handle the selection (iPad or iPhone version of the view) ?
What is the best way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your iPhone nib is named, MyApp.xib, name the iPad nib to "MyApp~ipad.xib" (mind the lowercase "P"). The latter one will automatically be loaded for iPad.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create specific view for iPhone and iPad,when you  create a new project -> Select Device Family as "Universal"  .2 xib files will be created. One for iPhone and another  for iPad respectively which you can use to design iPhone and iPad interface.